# Need suggestion for handling click events on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which spawns a CardView containing another RecyclerView.

The parent RecyclerView Adapter sets the child RecyclerView Adapter in order to render the following image. (The red text are added to show which position):
[image]

My question is how do I get the positions of what was clicked such as Parent 0 and Child 0 to signify the first parent RecyclerView with the first child RecyclerView was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewHolder item is your list item so implement on click listener on it 
and you can get clicked position on item click as: 
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
View.OnClickListener {
ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
   itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    System.out.println("clicked position "+getAdapterPosition());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would you get the parent RecyclerView adapater position? I have applied the same concept to the parent ViewHolder and it does not get called.

Comment: did you set click listener?if yes then where your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom RecyclerView Listener

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```

then in your activity implement above class

```
recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view1, int position) {
        CardView item_card = (CardView) view1.findViewById(R.id.item_card);
        item_card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view2) {
                //you code here
            }
        });
    }
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have followed it through and have a question as to how do I access the position number of the RecyclerView inside of the item_card?